# Can I retrieve the API interfaces via the API?

Tags: support, api

I'd like to retrieve a list of methods with their arguments/defaults and their return types through automated means.  Is this possible and, if so, how can I do it?

This isn't just for curiosity's sake; I plan on trying to use this in a [Stack Exchange mode for Emacs](https://stackapps.com/q/3950/11299).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do this anymore via the API.  [API self-documentation was intentionally dropped after API version 1.1.](https://stackapps.com/q/3222/7653)

Your only recourse is to scrape [the doc pages at `api.stackexchange.com/docs`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

Comment: After reviewing the answer (I was mobile before and assumed), I decided I need to be more clear: I don't necessarily care about documentation; I care about the actual interfaces and the objects they return.

Comment: Semantics. How is that any different? (specify) The answer remains the same and remains valid.

Comment: I trust you if you say there is no way to do it—I just wanted to make my question clear :)